# Cisco Webex - new attendeeSendVideo option

Tags: ruby, xml, webex

Aparently Cisco Webex has upgraded their APIs and now the service `CreateTrainingSession` has a new option `attendeeSendVideo`, that option turns ON attendees web cameras by default.

The [documentation](https://help.webex.com/en-us/hlvvgf/Cisco-Webex-Meetings-XML-API-Updates-Overview-XML-API-39-and-Earlier) does not mention where to put the new option `attendeeSendVideo` in the XML.

Wondering if this is new option goes in the `body` or `header` as a child property.

XML:

```xml
webex_request.body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" 
encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<serv:message 
  xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
  xmlns:serv=\"http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service\">
<header>
  <securityContext>
    <webExID>#{webExId}</webExID>
    <password>#{ENV['WEB_EX_PWD']}</password>
    <siteID>#{ENV['WEB_EX_SITE_ID']}</siteID>
  </securityContext>
</header>
<body>
  <bodyContent 
    xsi:type=\"java:com.webex.service.binding.training.CreateTrainingSession\">
    <schedule>
      <duration>#{duration}</duration>
    </schedule>
    <metaData>
      <confName>#{title}</confName>
    </metaData>
  </bodyContent>
</body>
</serv:message>"
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says to add extra **options** in here `enableOptions`

https://developer.cisco.com/docs/webex-xml-api-reference-guide/#!createtrainingsession/createtrainingsession

```
<bodyContent 
  xsi:type=\"java:com.webex.service.binding.training.CreateTrainingSession\">
  <schedule>
    <duration>#{duration}</duration>
  </schedule>
  <metaData>
    <confName>#{title}</confName>
  </metaData>
  <enableOptions>
    <attendeeSendVideo>true</attendeeSendVideo>
  </enableOptions>
</bodyContent>
```